# Accidentally changed permissions 777 to system files on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu server and I’m now locked out

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I accidentally changed the permissions of all files in the system to 777. Now nothing works. The website no longer works, I cannot start MySQL, I cannot connected FTP, I cannot connect to IP address with puTTY and I cannot enter the `sudo su`. I can use the command line DigitalOcean but when I login I automatically get logged out. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: there is no good answer  to an out-of-control chown/chmod, other than to restore from backup or rebuild. Sometimes a very dedicated community member will write up a script that resets default permissions for a given distro, but I haven't seen one of those since Ubuntu Gutsy. Even then they are essentially useless as all non-default files will still have the incorrect permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is a command that can restore the default permissions?

Comment: no probably not. you can search around for your exact version of ubunutu, but it is unlikely that you will find something that meets your needs. additionally since you don't have access to a physical shell on the machine, and you cannot login, there isn't a lot of option to run such a script even if you had one. I would try contacting their support, but in all likelihood, unless you have a backup, they won't support fixing your issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I asked support, await response.

Answer (score 2):

By 'all files in the system', I presume you mean `/`

In that case, it's a lot easier to reinstall than undo the damage, to be honest. I did something similar once, but limited to only one (rather large) directory, and I think I spent days fixing it all, manually. System-wide it's even worse.